# Python: How to import a class with libraries

Tags: python-3.x, object, initialization, python-import

Python 3.6 on Windows 10

Code:

> myClass.Py

```
**from Option_A import Stuff**
class foo:
    **from Option_B import Stuff**
    def __init__(self):
        **from Option_C import Stuff**
        Stuff.bar()
    def do_it_to_it(self, input)
        return Stuff.bar(input)
```

> myProgram.Py

```
from myClass import foo
ClassInstance = foo()
ClassInstance.bar("Hello")
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'Stuff' is not defined
```

I've tried Options A,B, and C but I can't get either to work

Thanks in advance for your help!

-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A is correct** -- I wasn't properly reloading my import of Stuff when I tested the various options.

I'm not deleting the question in case someone else has a similar question.

V/R,

-E